# Is it possible to reference the numbers in a function/equation?

Tags: excel

Example:
=[num1] + [num2] + [num3]

Is it possible to use num# from the equation? I'm trying to separate them.
=1+2+3
to A1 having 1, B1 having 2, etc.

Clearly, if I started from them being separate, I wouldn't have this problem, but is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use MID() with FORMULATEXT() to get the parts of the formula.

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner it works wonderfully! Can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as a solution? Or is there another way. Sorry I'm new.

Comment: my comment is only a suggestion that you took to make your answer.  Feel free to post your own answer and mark it as correct when you can.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
="="&A1&"+"&B1&"+"&C1
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for this? If not, please mention clearly what you want?

Comment: He wants to go backwards.  He has the formula and wants the parts.

Comment: Yes, what Scott has said, I have the formula but want the parts.